# Firebase hosting multi site, 1 domain, 2 sub domains

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I am building a website that has both an app and a control panel. I want the app to live at someurl.com and the control panel to be at controlpanel.someurl.com.

I have the someurl.com app setup, however the sub domain has confused me. From what I gather, the subdomain needs to be setup using the host of “controlpanel” and that it should point at a URL (e.g 115.110.145). My question is, what url should the subdomain point at, as firebase only gives me one URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All domains that are connected to Firebase Hosting utilize the same anycast IP addresses -- the Firebase Hosting serving infrastructure looks at the hostname of incoming requests to match to verified domains.

I'd recommend just following the steps in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) and would reach out to Firebase support if you get stuck in a specific place.